# How to run script multiple times and after every execution of command to wait until the device is ready to execute again?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /etc/stress.txt
cat /dev/smd10 | tee /etc/stress.txt &

for ((i=0; i< 1000; i++))
do
echo -e "\nRun number: $i\n" 
#wait untill module restart and bee ready for next restart
dmesg | grep ERROR
echo -e 'AT+CFUN=1,1\r\n' > /dev/smd10 
echo -e "\nADB device booted successfully\n" 
done
```

I want to restart module 1000 times using this script.

Module is like android device witch has linux inside it. But I use Windows.

AT+CFUN=1,1 - reset

When I push script, after every restart I need a command which will wait module and start up again and execute script 1000 times. Then I do pull in .txt file and save all output content.

Which command should I use?

I try commands like wait, sleep, watch, adb wait-for-device, ps aux | grep... Nothing works.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Does the module write something, anything, after restart?

Comment: Do you have /proc/modules ? (A simple grep _module_ Live should suffice)

Comment: @KamilCuk Module writes OK after AT+CFUN and those 3 echo messages

Comment: Then how can you check if it's restated? How do you know? Why didn't you specify what device is it? What system are you using? How is it connected? Etc?

Comment: @KamilCuk Module writes OK after AT+CFUN and I can see in Device Manager that ports are closed and green diode on device turns off. I'm using windows, local network.

Comment: I edit my question  so maybe now it will be better for understand.

Comment: @Zilod80 my module is embms_kernel 16384 2 - Live 0x504a37ad

Comment: What aspect doesn't work at the moment, please?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Module restarts just 1 time instead of 1000. I need a command which will wait for module to restart and to be ready for next 999 restarts.

Comment: Your script looks like it runs 1000 times to me. What happens when you run it?

Comment: @Mark Setchell When I run the script the output writes like it runs 1000 times but actually first time when module restarts it takes 30 seconds to be ready for startup. So I need command witch will wait until module is ready. It takes a log time to execute this script, maybe a couple of hours.

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg | grep embms_kernel`  after the reset command and before the module is ready ? And after the module is ready ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. This is how my script actually looks:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/smd10 &

TEST=$(cat /etc/output.txt) 
RESTART_TIMES=1000 
 
if [[ $TEST != $RESTART_TIMES ]] 
then
 echo $((TEST+1)) > /etc/output.txt 
 dmesg
 echo -e 'AT+CFUN=1,1\r\n' > /dev/smd10 
fi
```

These are the steps that you need to do:

1. adb push /path/to/your/script /etc/init.d
2. cd /etc
3. cat outputfile.txt - make an output file and write inside file 0 ( echo 0 > output.txt )
4. cd init.d
5. ls - you should see rc5.d
6. cd .. then cd rc5.d - go inside
7. ln -s ../init.d/yourscript.sh S99yourscript.sh
8. ls - you should see S99yourscript.sh
9. cd .. return to init.d directory
10. chmod +x yourscript.sh - add permision to your script
11. ./yourscript.sh